ImportError: `load_weights` requires h5py package when loading weights from HDF5. Try installing h5py
How can I fix this error? h5py is installed.
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from h5py) (1.24.3)
Python 3.11.7
TIA!
Uninstall and reinstalling with different versions to no avail.
I'm trying to use VGG16 and it requires weights.
